# Comunicação entre back-end e fron-end

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, front-end, back-end

Estou aprendendo ReactJS, fiz no front-end uma tela simples de cadastro e fiz o back-end gerando apis com NodeJs, seguindo esse tutorial: https://jsao.io/2018/03/creating-a-rest-api-with-node-js-and-oracle-database/

Agora preciso saber como faço a comunicação entre meu back-end e meu front-end ?

Ja que estão em projetos separados(fiz o front em uma pasta, o back em outra)

Comment: Com [requisições HTTP](https://reactjs.org/community/data-fetching.html).

Comment: Tu tem que postar os seus códigos, para ver exatamente como resolver seu problema.

Comment: @JonathandeToni pode ser pelo git ? https://github.com/VeronicaEms/apiRest 
Este é todo meu backend com as apis.

Comment: Descrevendo o problema geral você vai conseguir apenas uma resposta geral. Exemplo: "Como construir uma casa?", "Use blocos e cimento, construa paredes sólidas.". Em vez disso pergunte algo específico e respondível de forma útil: "Como levantar uma parede usando esse tipo de bloco com tal inclinação e de tal altura de forma segura?", resposta: "Posicione os blocos no formato tal, execute esse algoritmo de colocação de blocos, não use essa ferramenta pois há o risco tal, aqui tem um exemplo funcionando de uma parede pronta para você ver como faz [link]". Vê? Perguntas muito amplas não ajudam.

Comment: Tem várias libs/frameworks para isso, vc pode começar dando uma olhada no axios: > http://codeheaven.io/how-to-use-axios-as-your-http-client-pt/ verifique o item "Usando axios no browser", caso não esteja usando algo como vue/react

Comment: @VerônicaEmschermann, está faltando o front  u.u

Comment: O link do @AndersonCarlosWoss explica o que é o minimo necessário para quem vai tabalhar com WEB, não só website, mas qualquer aplicação que se comunique, muitos programas se tornam ruins porque as pessoas não entendem o minimo disto e acabam por se perder no caminho. Para criar o rest vc tem que ter um servidor local ou um servidor hospedado na web (no final vai ser hospedado) para servir os dados, isso é server-side, aonde se encontrará sua web-API (rest)

Answer (score -1):

Como você está usando React no front-end, você pode usar o axios para fazer uma requisição para sua API e receber o JSON com os dados e exebir na UI, assim como você pode fazer métodos POST para enviar dados para sua API que deve inserir no banco.

Esse link pode te ajudar -> [clica aqui](https://alligator.io/react/axios-react/)

Answer (score -2):

Olá, você deve dá uma lida em REST, pois para você encaminhar as requisições que o front irá conceber ao usuário para o back é necessário utilizar o protocolo HTTP. Leia o seguinte artigo (pequeno, mas demonstra o que é REST):

https://becode.com.br/o-que-e-api-rest-e-restful/